# Unity Question sorting a cube behind 2d sprite

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, user-interface, video, background

I'm using a cube for the video player compotentent. And I have a sprite that I want to put in front of the cube. But there not a an option for sorting layer so how would I put the sprite infront of the cube.

I've tried using a square but the video player doesn't work.

I've messed with layers and the z position.

Answer (score 0):

in the hierarchy, if 2 objects have the same z position, the one on top will appear in front. so if you want the cube to be behind simply move it under the sprite (not a child).

Comment: That did not resolve the issue. I tried that instantly.

Comment: are you using unity 2d or 3d? @NoraPī

Comment: Apologies, it is unity 2d.

Comment: changing z position did work for me, can you share photos that could help?

Comment: I ended up Scrapping the cube using a square and dragging and dropping the mp3 on the square and it worked. Long story short You can't put a 2d in front of a 3d.